# VPX radial clock vs bussed clock

Tags: clock, standard

I'm learning some concepts about OpenVPX. One thing I am a bit confused about is the notion of a radial clock versus a bussed clock. I'm not getting many helpful Google hits.

Can someone explain the architectural difference, and maybe why you'd choose one over the other?

Comment: Please link to the article where you read about this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Radial vs Tree vs Bus architectures are pretty well defined on the web.

When latency is critical so that differential measurements depend on null differences such as some analog RADAR measurements you want RADIAL.

When you can re-sync data to either edge of the clock, then a BUS will do and latency may be computed like RAM for core clock cycles of delay for read, write , address etc operations.

OpenVPX is the new military std that replaces VME for defining RF interfaces etc.